# How to resolve "KeyError: 2"

Tags: python, keyerror

When I run my application in the following block I get KeyError 2:

```
if bool(self.access):  # to check if it is empty or not
    if no in self.access[idno]:
        if (idno, no) in self.table:
            if self.table[(idno, no)] == (idx, macx):
                return
            else:
                self.table[(idno, no)] = (idx, macx)
                return
        else:
            self.table.setdefault((idno, no), set())
            self.table[(idno, no)] = (idx, macx)
            return
```

I have to mention that at some point in the program I call `self.access.clear()`.
 Even though I have added the  first two if conditions but I still get the following error:

```
line 189, in register_idx
    if no in self.access[dpid]:
KeyError: 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `if bool(...)` is redundant. It should be `if ...` instead,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking first if `self.access` contains *anything*, and then assuming it contains `idno`. In this case, it didn't, and `idno` happened to be `2`. Nothing in this code snippet populates `self.access`, so I don't know what you expect of it.

Comment: Thank you @yann-vernier, I think I understand the problem now.